# Disable auto rescheduling for a pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

On k8s cluster (GCP) during nodes auto-scaling, my pods are rescheduled automatically. The main problem that they perform computations and keep results in memory during auto-scaling. Because of rescheduling, pods lose all results and tasks.

I want to disable rescheduling for specified pods. I know a few possible solutions:

- nodeSelector (not very flexible due to the dynamic nature of a cluster)
- pod disruption budget PDB

I have tried PDB and set minAvailable = 1 but it didn't work. I found that you can also set maxUnavailable=0, will it more effective? I didn't understand exactly the behaviour if maxUnavailable when it's set to 0. Could you explain it more? Thank you!

Link for more details - https://github.com/dask/dask-kubernetes/issues/112

Answer (score 1):

Setting max unavailable to 0 is a way to go and also, using nodepools can be a good workaround.

```
gcloud container node-pools create <nodepool> --node-taints=app=dask-scheduler:NoSchedule
gcloud container node-pools create <nodepool> --node-labels app=dask-scheduler
```

This will create the nodepool with the label app=dask-scheduler, after in the pod spec, you can do this:

```
nodeSelector:
  app: dask-scheduler
```

And put the dask scheduler on a node-pool that doesn't autoscale.

There's an object called PDB where in its spec you can set maxUnavailable
in the example of maxUnavailable=1, this means if you had 100 pods defined, always make sure there is only one removed/drained/re-scheduled at a time
in the case of maxUnavailable, if you have 2 pods, and you set maxUnavailable to 0, it will never remove your pods. It being the scheduler

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: zk-pdb
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
```

Comment: I have tested PDB maxUnavailable=0 . It doesn't work, dask-scheduler is still recreated.

Comment: Regarding the issue, is there a specific pod(s) that is restarting?

Comment: Yes, dask scheduler pod that control tasks execution.

Comment: BTW, is it possible to setup both minAvailable and maxUnavailable?

Comment: No, it's not possible to setup both minAvailable and maxUnavailable. This is a mutually exclusive setting with "minAvailable". I recommend you to have a look at this [article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#poddisruptionbudget-v1beta1-policy) on Kubernetes website.

Comment: Is GCP Kuberntes engine auto-scaler tolerates PDB during scaling up? Or scaling depends on Kuberntes only?

Comment: If the scheduler needs to schedule a pod and there is insufficient resources, it will request another node. The CA will then determine if a new node is possible (based on min/max defined) or if a new node will help. So, it has nothing to do with PDB.

Comment: The main problem is that pod is resheduled during scale up and CA doesn't tolerate PDB in this situtation. On the opposite site, during scale down everything is good.

Comment: Please note minAvailable is just to make sure there will be some instance to answer. And if it needs to be one no specific node is running all the time - you can [create a separate service w/o scaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/understanding-autoscaler-decisions) (one node). There are just two [possibilities](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#think-about-how-your-application-reacts-to-disruptions). 1) Do not use a PDB and tolerate occasional downtime. 2) Set PDB with maxUnavailable=0 as we talked about it earlier and you said it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying resource requests and limits?

Comment: Yes, I am using requests and limits for pods